# matching indexes in python to categorize a column

Tags: python, match, dataframe

I have a column in a dataframe of length 1083 with 143 unique values. To illustrate my question, 6 of these are:

1. bakery
2. hospital
3. hotel
4. dentist
5. university
6. restaurant

I have created another dataframe, 2x1. The first column contains the 143 unique values, and the second contains what I want each of them to be categorised as. eg:

```
 1. bakery       commercial
 2. hospital     commerical
 3. hotel        hospitality
 4. dentist      commercial
 5. university   education
 6. restaurant   hospitality
```

I was wondering how I would create a new column in my original df, matching the indices such that for any entry in the column that = 'bakery', would then be 'commercial' in the new column.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure how to format my second list: The first word of each numbered point is in 1 column, the second word of each is in a second column

Comment: check out merge functions in python

Comment: This is exactly the function I needed - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `merge` and do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.merge(  left=firstDataFrame, right=secondDataFrame, on='NameOfColumnContainingBakery...')
```

The column name in `on=''` needs to be the same in both dataframes.

This merges the two dataframes into a single one, which contains an additional column as you described it.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you may use dictionaries defined somewhere in your program... refer to it whenever you are trying to create a new column ...

```
categories = {"bakery" : "commercial", ... }
```

then you call the dictionary whenever you need to extract its corresponding value:

```
categories["bakery"] # will return "commercial"
```